# Is it possible to use the mapped key value in react somehow?

Tags: reactjs

Is there a way to access a key value in React? To clarify, I mean the value of a key that was created using map in jsx, not key value pairs.

Ex...  if(the keys value){do something}

If so, how would I go about accessing the value in my code?

Comment: You are talking about the key pro which is being passed to the component while mapping a array right?

Comment: React keys are for react's benefit and so they are not exposed to you inside the component. If you want to access that value inside the component, pass it in using a prop. Eg, `<SomeComponent key="123" theKey="123" />`, then access props.theKey

Comment: Okay thanks. I can manage it like that. I  Just wanted to make sure there wasn't a direct way to access it built in.